# ошибка импорта в ReactTS + webpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, node-modules

хочу собрать проект на ReactTS + webpack  столкнулся с проблемой: установил все необходимые модули и нисмотря на это в файле index.tsx  я сталкиваюсь с ошибками[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 {
  "name": "my-webpack-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My webpack project",
  "main": "src/index.tsx",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production --node-env=production",
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode=development",
    "build:prod": "webpack --mode=production --node-env=production",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "serve": "webpack serve"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@webpack-cli/generators": "^3.0.4",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.1",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.62.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4",
    "webpack": "^5.84.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте: npm install --save react react-dom @types/react @types/react-dom